# Weird ASP.NET Razor page error in Javascript For loop: Name cannot begin with the character

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

Web page displays an ASP.NET error like below:

[image]

The line is pure JS code. I could track down the exact line in for loop:

[image]

I have no idea what's wrong with JS code in Razor page. If I remove for loop, the error disappears. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please try to avoid screenshots in your quesiton and post the code directly. On first glance I cant really see an issue and I was able to run the code on my machine. Are you declaring len or i somewhere else? Please also get rid of the var keyword and use let instead to use block-scoping. Var can always be a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason; Razor engine encodes the < and > characters so the browser throws JS compile error:

[image]

The solution is simple:

1- Wrapping inside the < script> < /script> tags with <! -- -->

2- Using @Html.Raw("<") instead of <

```
<script>
<!--  

...
// i < len;  // Replace this line as below
i @Html.Raw("<") len;
...
-->
</script>
```